Closing a parent element when a child is clicked (JS)
I am having a little trouble with some JS.
Currently, I have a button class, 'mobilecollapsible', which opens a div, 'mobilecollapsiblecontent' when it's clicked. It opens and closes fine when you click the button. The div contains a  list of links.
However, I would like the div to close when any link within it is closed.
Here is the relevant code:
JS:


var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("mobilecollapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var mobilecollapsiblecontent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (mobilecollapsiblecontent.style.display === "block") {
      mobilecollapsiblecontent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      mobilecollapsiblecontent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
<button type="button" class="mobilecollapsible"><strong>Filter by Options: <strong class="plussign">+</strong></strong></button>
<div class="mobilecollapsiblecontent">
 <ul class="ul-transactionfilterlist">
  <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="all"><strong>All</strong></button></li>
  <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="option1">Option1</button></li>
  <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="option2">Option2</button></li>
  <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="option3">Option3</button></li>
 </ul>
</div>



I am an idiot when it comes to JS so I have no idea where to amend this code.

As is, this code doesn't seem to do anything. But wondering if you might want to look into the closest method.

I would imagine you would want to start with an event handler on galleryfilterbutton

There are no links in your HTML. What do you mean by "any link within it is closed."?

@mykaf The first click doesn't do anything, but clicking on the filter button a second time works.

Add a click event listener to the content divs that closes it.
I've also changed your original event listener to use getComputedStyle(). The .style property only returns inline styles, not styles that come from CSS, which is why it doesn't work on the first click.


var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("mobilecollapsible");

for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var mobilecollapsiblecontent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (getComputedStyle(mobilecollapsiblecontent).getPropertyValue("display") === "block") {
      mobilecollapsiblecontent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      mobilecollapsiblecontent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

let content = document.querySelectorAll(".mobilecollapsiblecontent");

content.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", () => el.style.display = "none"));
<button type="button" class="mobilecollapsible"><strong>Filter by Options: <strong class="plussign">+</strong></strong></button>
<div class="mobilecollapsiblecontent">
  <ul class="ul-transactionfilterlist">
    <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="all"><strong>All</strong></button></li>
    <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="option1">Option1</button></li>
    <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="option2">Option2</button></li>
    <li class="li-transactionfilterlist"><button class="galleryfilterbutton" data-filter="option3">Option3</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>




Barmar, you are a hero - this now works perfectly. Thank you for your help with this.
